# Upload an existing database in mySQL or XML in Odoo

Tags: mysql, xml, odoo

We are busy with a webshop project. We need an ERP software that can communicate with the webshop. After searching for a while, we found Odoo. But I contacted an Odoo partner for more information but that was not sufficient.

We already have an existing catalog database in MySQL. We can convert MySQL database in XML that will not be a problem.

My question is:
is it possible to import our catalog database in Odoo?
The database is hierarchical (tree-like structure), the XML needs to be in specific form?

If somebody can help me with this, or help me to find more information about this issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/data.html)

You could build from mysql database one or more XML file with this record structure:

```
<record id="id_of_this_record" model="your_model_name">
    <field name="field_name_1">field value for strings</field>
    <field name="field_name_2" eval="field value for integers etc: can be a python expression"/>
    <field name="field_name_3" ref="id of another record previously declared"/>
    <field name="field_name_4" eval="[(6, False, [ref('id of another record previously declared'),ref('id of another record previously declared')])]"/>

</record>
```

where *field_name_3* is the special case of a many2one relationship field while *field_name_4* is the special case of a one2many/many2many relationship field

these should more or less cover all of your cases

Another way is to use [CSV](http://www.slideshare.net/openobject/best-practices-on-how-to-import-data-into-openerp-cyril-morisse-consultant-audaxis) but i am not very familiar with them in odoo